# How to disable the start up beep (on a Windows machine)?

Tags: windows-vista, audio

When I turn my computer on it makes an annoying beep (even if the speakers are turned off).

Here's what does **not** work:

- Disabling the Beep-Device in the Device Manager
- I'm not talking about the Windows start up sound (which can be disabled in the sounds section of the control panel)

Since this beep sounds a short time after turning the PC on, I suppose it is connect to a *deeper* part of the computer (maybe the BIOS)?

Any idea how to turn it off?

**Edit**: I didn't find any obvious way to disable the beep in the BIOS.
Where would I usually find such an option in it?

Answer (score 5):

That the beep may come from the BIOS during the POST may very well be the reason. Have a look into your BIOS' settings, there could be an option like "Beep during POST" or similar.

The sledgehammer solution would be to disconnect the internal speaker from you mainboard. The speaker itself is often integrated into your case, but you can usually (reversibly) disconnect it by pulling the connector off the mainboard.

Comment: Note that if you do this, you'll no longer get "Beep Codes" from the bios when things aren't working right.  So remember to re-connect the speaker if your machine doesn't boot for any reason.

Comment: @Paul is definitely right on this--that beep at the start **is** a beep code--the one reporting success.  Note that it might not even go to a case speaker--on this box it's just a little fat-pencil-eraser sized cylinder with a connector that plugs in to a set of pins on the motherboard.